# How to change app.js to another in react-native expo-cli?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using react-native expo-cli v3.20.1. I want to change default App.js to Home.js. How to change my default js file? In my project folder I don't have index.js file to configure in latest expo cli

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try to define it in `app.json`:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "entryPoint": "./Home.js"
  }
}
```